# Error in recursive mapped type goes undetected. Why?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

See the code below or the [corresponding playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gWwgFXNAvFA3gKClAbQAUoBLAOygHIBXKgXQH4AuKAZ2ACcKBzAbhwBfKADJseQiQrUAhlSgAfagCN5SqgGM11ACYMWsRCjQDBOHBrjkO7YK3hJUkKJlz4arKgEYqAGgkyrG74UB7UAEx+EvjKQdEhYVQAzFEhIRpxaWk6mVn4gv55+BCsXr5QAPQVUADuABYgUDpwEGzkVMBQwHWkbFAaMjRs0DKUEJyccJxQdeMQjFBwAPJddaMA1lAgcDQAhPH58QUSx8Wl5VVQEAAekBrAEDpXE1OsS8oAVhD3UAA2pA9ODJflAEDJGlZfo02HdSAAzRrrchwGqUMCTSCcYCkVrlUZPKgQeTNVpQZGdG69TrSUDOKgOYyQKgAOiEAiAA):

```
type SomeType = {
  [P in 'u']?: string;
} & {
  [P in 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 'd']?: SomeType;
}

const st: SomeType = {
  u: '1',
  a: {
    u: '2',
    b: {
      u: '3',
      c: {
        d: {
        },
        e: 1, // why doesn't this cause an error here? oO thank you!
      }
    },
  },
  e: 1, // expected error: Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'e' does not exist in type 'SomeType'.
};
```

I don't know what else to say here. If you comment out the last `e: 1` then no ts error is generated. Why?

**Edit:** OK, like [wtf](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gWwgFXNAvFA3gKClAVwH4AuKAZ2ACcBLAOwHMBuPKAQ1NkRTRfwCNO8JKkh8oAYyHdREcQBNpI3jgC%20OHBLh1KFYGWE9IUTLnwEyAcgCMlgDSs2ZM-kJWATPdYDn31xahLAGYvV1cJXzCw%20Uio-FUHOPwIMms7KAB6DKgIAA9ICWAIeRyqKjgqMgB5fgArCEKoABsaIqo2JqgENhAobSbe8gKaADNegGs6OAB3OigwcsgqYBoIcnS2OhLLCEsoeTg1qCngHNyaXXooUGNLQ1lLADo-eL8E1nfk1PSss4KikoQMoVap1BqnFptDpdHp9OgDCjDMZQSYzOYLOBLFZrDZbQK7faHcjHOCnPIXU5XG7QO4yNBPNQsIA).

```
type SomeType = {
  u?: string;
  a?: SomeType;
  b?: SomeType;
  c?: SomeType;
  d?: SomeType;
}

const st: SomeType = {
  u: '1',
  a: {
    u: '2',
    b: {
      u: '3',
      c: {
        d: {
        },
        e: 1, // expected error: Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'e' does not exist in type 'SomeType'.
      }
    },
  },
  e: 1, // expected error: Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'e' does not exist in type 'SomeType'.
};
```

**Edit:** [Here is the fixed version](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAClC8UDkBXJBuAUKSUCKCyAhklAD7IBGpFSAxjcgCYabbjQDKA9gLYQAVDoQDemKFADaAaSgBLAHZQAFHAp4AlAF0A-AC4osiAA9gEBUwDOscRKg6ol4ACdFAc1sSDPfkMiYAXyxMOm4FJ0dgbz5BYUQxCRQDJABGJAAaWyIDBLsk5AAmDM8oShySxOSAZmK7OzpyurqmRqaJAMy2iQgDFPSoAHoBqBNIOjMmEednbmcDAHlKACsIcagAGzkzZyJ1qF4iECgw9aPLMbkAMyOAawVuAHclMBnIZ2A5CEt%20ogtkCFITG4Xyg92AI2McgiiigOGgSB8sUgSAAdBUoAESh1bNjur1%20kMIWMJlMZnMoIsVmtNttdvtDscFKdHBdrlA7o9nq8IO9Pt8oL9JkgAVAgSCwRCoeCYXDkIi-AC0UFMEA) I created with the advice from [@tokland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/188031/tokland) that recursion with intersection is broken.

```
type P = 'u';
type Q = 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 'd';

type SomeType = {
  [K in (P | Q)]?: K extends P
    ? string
    : SomeType
};

const st: SomeType = {
  u: '1',
  a: {
    u: '2',
    b: {
      u: '3',
      c: {
        d: {
        },
        e: 1, // expected error: Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'e' does not exist in type 'SomeType'.
      }
    },
  },
  e: 1, // expected error: Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'e' does not exist in type 'SomeType'.
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a known bug, excess property check for nested type intersections  worked fine up until 3.8:

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47935

3.8: [working](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.8.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gWwgFXNAvFA3gKClAbQAUoBLAOygHIBXKgXQH4AuKAZ2ACcKBzAbhwBfKADJseQiQrUAhlSgAfagCN5SqgGM11ACYMWsRCjQDBOHBrjkO7YK3hJUkKJlz4arKgEYqAGgkyrG74UB7UAEx+EvjKQdEhYVQAzFEhIRpxaWk6mVn4gv55+BCsXr5QAPQVUADuABYgUDpwEGzkVMBQwHWkbFAaMjRs0DKUEJyccJxQdeMQjFBwAPJddaMA1lAgcDQAhPH58QUSx4ICQA)

3.9: [not working](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.9.7#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gWwgFXNAvFA3gKClAbQAUoBLAOygHIBXKgXQH4AuKAZ2ACcKBzAbhwBfKADJseQiQrUAhlSgAfagCN5SqgGM11ACYMWsRCjQDBOHBrjkO7YK3hJUkKJlz4arKgEYqAGgkyrG74UB7UAEx+EvjKQdEhYVQAzFEhIRpxaWk6mVn4gv55+BCsXr5QAPQVUADuABYgUDpwEGzkVMBQwHWkbFAaMjRs0DKUEJyccJxQdeMQjFBwAPJddaMA1lAgcDQAhPH58QUSx4ICQA)

Comment: That issue predates TS3.9 by quite a bit; are you sure you have the version right?

Comment: That's what I tested: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.8.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gWwgFXNAvFA3gKClAbQAUoBLAOygHIBXKgXQH4AuKAZ2ACcKBzAbhwBfKADJseQiQrUAhlSgAfagCN5SqgGM11ACYMWsRCjQDBOHBrjkO7YK3hJUkKJlz4arKgEYqAGgkyrG74UB7UAEx+EvjKQdEhYVQAzFEhIRpxaWk6mVn4gv55+BCsXr5QAPQVUADuABYgUDpwEGzkVMBQwHWkbFAaMjRs0DKUEJyccJxQdeMQjFBwAPJddaMA1lAgcDQAhPH58QUSx4ICQA vs same in 3.9.7

Comment: As far as I can see this has nothing to do with 3.9 and is still an issue with TS 4.7.2 (see playground) The issue is closed / resolved. Is there something I am not understanding here correctly? (most likely) Will have a deeper look after taking my shower / break. Thank you so much for the intersection recursion hint. I updated my question with a workaround solution. You're my king.

Comment: Sorry guys, I mixed up the links, updated!